# Trying to replicate netflix background image

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to replicate this image but so far this is what I have done. the image doesn't blur after the background image
What I want to do
[The netflix image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x7YmM.jpg)

What I have done
[my image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUd8B.jpg)

here is my source code for Featured.js

```
import React from 'react'
import './featured.scss'
import background from '../../assets/background1.png'
import info from '../../assets/info1.png'
import { InfoOutlined, PlayArrow } from "@material-ui/icons";
const Featured = () => {
  return (
    <div className='featured'>
        <img className='background' src={background} alt="" />
        {/* <div className="shadow"></div> */}
        <div className="info">
            <img src={info} alt="" />
            {/* <span className="desc">
            Based on historical events, this series dramatizes the story of Queen Elizabeth II and the political and personal events that have shaped her reign.
            </span> */}
            <div className="buttons">
            <button className="play">
                <PlayArrow className='arrow' />
                <span>Play</span>
            </button>
            <button className="more">
                <InfoOutlined />
                <span>More Info</span>
            </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Featured
```

featured.scss

```
.featured{
    height: 110vh;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom 0%, rgb(0,0,0,0.3) 50%);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 0px linear-gradient(rgb(0,0,0,0.3));
    position: relative;

    img.background{
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        object-fit: cover;
        background: linear-gradient(to top,transparent 0%, rgb(0,0,0,0.3) 50%);
        z-index: -999;
    }
    .info {
        width: 35%;
        position: absolute;
        left: 50px;
        bottom: 200px;
        color: white;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        margin-top: -40px;
    
        img {
          width: 300px;
          position: relative;
          // z-index: 99;
        }
    
        .desc {
          margin: 20px 0px;
          z-index: 99;
        }
    
        .buttons {
          display: flex;
          z-index: 99;
          margin-top: 20px;
    
          button {
            padding: 5px 20px;
            border: none;
            border-radius: 5px;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            font-size: 18px;
            font-weight: 500;
            margin-right: 10px;
            cursor: pointer;
    
            &.play {
              background-color: white;
              color: var(--main-color);
            //   font-size: 30px;
              .arrow{
                font-size: 30px;
                font-weight: bold;
              }
            }
    
            &.more {
              background-color: gray;
              color: white;
            }
    
            span {
              margin-left: 5px;
            }
          }
        }
      }
}
```

pls help me what can I do the background of my image is not blurring, what is wrong with the code

Comment: where are you applying the blur?

Comment: at the bottom of the background image an example is at netflix.com, at the bottom of the background image or hero image there is a blur on it

Comment: yes, but which part of your code attempts to apply that effect?

Comment: Maybe, the scss, or it can be hard coded in react all my attempts failed so I don't know

Answer (score 0):

You can think of the blur as a CSS Gradient from transparent to black, on top of the image you can have another div which has a background vertical gradient from transparent to black, this way you can achieve the blur in the bottom of the background

CSS

```
background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 70%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%);
```

FYI Netflix is built on [React](https://rootstack.com/en/blog/why-netflix-chose-react-build-its-user-interface), so you might want to learn it if you're going to be building more projects like this one